# How to validate inputted data from that backed up with a CSV without a purpose built CSV parser

Tags: java, csv

I need to be able to verify a user inputted email and password against a csv file which I have that have to make sure that they are in the file and also that they match each other such as;
ojones@coldmail.net ocrabc. Currently I can split the file and print it to the screen but I cannot find a way to put it into an array which I can then refer to. Is there a better way of solving such a problem without an array?

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CSVRead{

public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader CSVFile =
        new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testa453.csv"));
    String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
    while (dataRow != null){
        String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
        for (String item:dataArray) {
            System.out.print(item + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
    }
    CSVFile.close();
    System.out.println();

}
```

}

EDIT; Just to clarify I am reasonably new to Java and would like to use and array unless there is a more efficient way of solving the problem;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) of e-mail -> password

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CSVRead{

public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> emailPasswordMap = new HashMap<String, String> ();
    BufferedReader CSVFile =
        new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testa453.csv"));
    String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
    while (dataRow != null){
        String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
        emailPasswordMap.put (dataArray[0], dataArray[1]);
        dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
    }
    CSVFile.close();

    String email = "xxx";
    String password = "yyy";

    if (password.equals (emailPasswordMap.get (email)) {
        System.out.println ("Email/password combination is valid");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println ("Email/password combination is invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful and I am looking into it but what I need the program to do is to simply output true if the email + password are valid. The user inputs both the password and email. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You don't have to read the whole file in - just do the comparison for each row of CSV. If you have a very large CSV file reading the whole file in is not very efficient and could cause memory issues.